# Safely save data to the order in onNotify()

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

I'm new to Drupal and have to make an off-site payment gateway (with Drupal Commerce 2). It all works, but sometimes it doesn't.

The remote payment provider's server sends notification requests to the server, about the status of the payment, so I have both `onReturn` and `onNotify` in the PaymentGateway class.

Since `onReturn` is not guaranteed to be called (the customer might close the browser, etc, and the provider does not necessarily send him back in my case), but `onNotify` is guaranteed to be called, I create and save the `Payment` object in `onNotify`, not in `onReturn`, when the payment is complete. (This is also what the documentation suggests to do: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/create-payment-gateway/off-site-gateways/handling-ipn)

So my code looks something like this. (It's a very simplified pseudo-code; validation checks aren't included.)

```php
class RedirectCheckout extends OffsitePaymentGatewayBase implements SupportsNotificationsInterface {

  public function onReturn() {
    $is_order_accepted = /* Check the remote payment provider has accepted the order */
    if (!$is_order_accepted) {
       throw new NeedsRedirectException()
    }
    // If all is good, do nothing.
  }

  public function onNotify() {
    /** @var OrderInterface $order */
    $order = /* Load the order the notification is about */

    $is_order_accepted = /* Check the remote payment provider has accepted the order */
    if ($is_order_accepted) {
      $payment = $payment_storage->create();
      $payment->save();
      $order->setData('transaction_id', $transactionId);
      $order->save(); // This is what sometimes overwritten by  onReturn(), I believe.
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I need to save some data on the order, when an order is accepted (which is not available when the order is created, only when a payment has succeeded).
The Drupal Commerce documentation says you "don't need to (and should not)" touch the order, but I have to save some extra data on the order that other parts on the system expects to be there.

This often works. However, the two `onReturn` and `onNotify` requests from the remote server sometimes arrives at almost the same time, which I believe leads to a race condition.

Unfortunately, even though I am not doing anything to the order in `onReturn`, Commerce seems to still save the order. I believe this can sometime overwrite the data saved to the order by `onNotify`. For example:

- `onReturn` starts running, and loads the order (This is done by the commerce library itself, so I can't do anything about this.)
- The notify request arrives, so `onNotify` starts running, loads and saves the order, and returns
- After this, the `onReturn` method returns, gives back control to Commerce, which saves the order again; since it loaded the order object before `onNotify` saved it, it overwrites whatever `onNotify` wrote with old data

(Perhaps the converse order can also be problematic, where `onNotify` can overwrite any data saved to the order by Drupal Commerce behind the scenes, if any, during the `onReturn` request.)

Is there a good way to handle this, for example work around the race-condition to be able to save order data in `onNotify`?

I'm using Drupal 8.6.

Comment: Have you tried to use events, such as `commerce_order.place.post_transition`?

Comment: Interesting idea - i will look into how that works

Comment: Good suggestion! Unfortunately, according to my tests, onNotify() doesn't place the order by itself (so this event isn't fired), when the payment is added. So the only way to place the order in onNotify(), is to "apply the transition" to the order and then save the order yourself - but then we're back to the concurrency problem above, unfortunately, since both onNotify() and onReturn() saves the order. (And i guess we would also have been back to that problem, if commerce placed the order by itself)

Answer (score 1):

You are right about race condition, but onReturn does not modify order at all

This is what happens in the background:

- the `commerce_payment.checkout.return` route on commerce payment
  module is called which at first it let order payment gateway plugin
  to create an payment for order
- then no matter what happens in the onReturn method of plugin order checkout flow will be redirected on another stage (if onReturn throws exception it will be redirected to previous stage else it will be redirect to next stage)
- in this situation the method  `redirectToStep` in the
  `Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowBase`
  will modify and save order which is where the problem happens.

this is the implementation of `redirectToStep`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function redirectToStep($step_id) {
  if (!$this->isStepVisible($step_id)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid step ID "%s" passed to redirectToStep().', $step_id));
  }

  $this->order->set('checkout_step', $step_id);
  $this->onStepChange($step_id);
  $this->order->save();

  throw new NeedsRedirectException(Url::fromRoute('commerce_checkout.form', [
    'commerce_order' => $this->order->id(),
    'step' => $step_id,
  ])->toString());
}
```

so to solve the problem in your onReturn method you should stand for onNotify changes to be done (a while loop which waits until changes on order are set)

hopes it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer! One question though - even if i in onReturn wait for the onNotify changes to be done, won't "$this->order" still contain the old values from before onNotify was run? (so redirectToStep will save the old values). If so, is there a way to reload "$this->order" in onReturn (after the wait)?

Comment: (Hmm... And couldn't saving the order in onNotify actually revert the change to "checkout_step" on the order done it redirectToStep to its old value?)

Comment: Actually I am not pretty sure about this situation but I guess this will work Ok, give it a try and if things didn't goes very well then we can think about other approaches